# No icons for moderncv with minimal LaTeX install

Tags: xetex, moderncv, docker

I am using a small image with a minimal LaTeX install. When I build a `moderncv` document, there aren't any icons for phone & mail. I have already added the `fontawesome` package in Dockerfile like this:

> RUN tlmgr install ctex moderncv fontawesome5 fontawesome academicons multirow arydshln && apk update && apk add rsync openssh sshpass && chmod +x cv-render && texhash

I am sure the LaTeX document was fine, because I can render the icon with the LaTeX full install. Am I missing something? this is the Dockerfile how to build the tex environment:

```
# https://github.com/kjarosh/latex-docker
FROM kjarosh/latex:2023.1-small
LABEL org.reddwarf.image.authors="jiangtingqiang@gmail.com"

ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
    TZ=Asia/Shanghai

WORKDIR /app
ENV ROCKET_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
COPY --from=builder /home/rust/src/settings-production.toml /app/settings.toml
COPY --from=builder /home/rust/src/script /app/
COPY --from=builder /home/rust/src/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/cv-render /app/
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/fonts/ && mkdir -p /app/config/ && mkdir -p /root/.ssh
COPY --from=builder /home/rust/src/texmf/tex/latex/ /opt/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/
COPY --from=builder /home/rust/src/config/font /usr/share/fonts/
COPY --from=builder /home/rust/src/log4rs.yaml /app/config/
COPY --from=builder /home/rust/src/config/ssh/known_hosts /root/.ssh/
RUN tlmgr install ctex moderncv fontawesome5 fontawesome academicons multirow arydshln && apk update && apk add rsync openssh sshpass && chmod +x cv-render && texhash
CMD ["sh","./startup-app.sh"]
```

this is my texfile:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\setmainfont{lmroman10-regular.otf}
\setlength{\footskip}{149.60005pt}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}

\name{蒋}{小强}
\title{高级Java开发工程师-蒋小强}
\phone[mobile]{15576865433}
\email{demo@gmail.com}
\social[stackoverflow]{https://stackoverflow.com/users/2628868/dolphin}
\social[github]{https://github.com/reddwarf}
\extrainfo{出生日期：1991年03月}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{教育经历}

\cventry{2009.09--2013.06}{本科}{中国药科大学}{江苏南京}{信息管理与信息系统}{}
\section{工作经历}

\cventry{2023.07--2023.07}{Java开发工程师}{重庆红矮星科技有限公司}{重庆大足}{}{
\begin{itemize}
\item 开发和维护Java应用程序
\item 根据需求分析进行软件设计和编码
\item 负责对现有系统进行优化和改进
\item 解决软件开发过程中的技术难题
\item 参与软件架构设计和代码评审
\item 与团队成员合作，并按时交付高质量的代码
\item 针对系统性能进行测试和优化
\item 负责系统文档的编写和维护
\item 遵守公司的开发规范和流程要求
\item 研究和应用新的Java技术和工具
\item 参与软件项目的需求分析和评估
\item 协助解决客户的技术问题
\item 提供技术指导和培训给其他团队成员
\end{itemize}
}

\section{专业技能}

\section{项目经历}

\cventry{2023.07--2023.07}{桌游后台}{上海即维信息科技有限公司}{上海}{}{
\begin{itemize}
\item 参与桌游后台项目的需求分析和功能设计
\item 负责后台系统的数据库设计和优化
\item 开发后台系统的接口和业务逻辑
\item 参与项目的部署和维护工作
\item 参与中台系统的需求评审和功能开发
\item 负责中台系统的数据库设计和性能优化
\item 开发中台系统的接口和业务逻辑
\item 参与游戏的压力测试和性能优化
\item 修复项目中的 bug 和问题
\item 协助团队成员解决技术难题
\item 参与项目的进度跟踪和风险评估
\item 提供技术支持和培训给其他团队成员
\end{itemize}
}


\end{document}
```

this is the generate pdf that did not contains the icon:

[image]

this is the log output, I did not found any exception with this log:

```
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of kerning.
Package microtype Info: Loading generic protrusion settings for font family
(microtype)             `lmroman10-regular.otf' (encoding: TU).
(microtype)             For optimal results, create family-specific settings.
(microtype)             See the microtype manual for details.

Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/n on inpu
t line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/n on inp
ut line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/n --> TU/lmroman10-regula
r.otf(0)/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/it on in
put line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/b/n on inp
ut line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/n --> TU/lmroman10-regula
r.otf(0)/b/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/b/it on i
nput line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/b/n on input line 22.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: xetex
* paper: a4paper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes:
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(74.68848pt, 448.1309pt, 74.68849pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(84.50467pt, 633.78513pt, 126.75705pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=448.1309pt
* \textheight=633.78513pt
* \oddsidemargin=2.41849pt
* \evensidemargin=2.41849pt
* \topmargin=-24.76532pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=149.60005pt
* \marginparwidth=57.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 22.
\@outlinefile=\write4
\openout4 = `modern.out'.


Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

\makecvheaddetailsbox=\box72

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/sl' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/it' instead on input l
ine 24.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/n' instead on input li
ne 24.

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <9> on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 24.
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg
File: mt-cmr.cfg 2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman
(RS)
)
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-TU-empty.cfg
File: mt-TU-empty.cfg 2021/06/22 v1.1 microtype config. file: fonts with nonsta
ndard glyph set (RS)
)
\makecvheadpicturebox=\box73
\makecvheaddetailswidth=\skip107
\makecvheadpicturewidth=\skip108
\makecvheadnamebox=\box74


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/sl' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/it' instead on input l
ine 24.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 24--24

 []

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 26.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/n' instead on input li
ne 28.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/sl' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/it' instead on input l
ine 28.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/sl' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/it' instead on input l
ine 47.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/sl' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/it' instead on input l
ine 68.

[1

] [2] (output/2023/7/96/38/1/modern.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.


Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `modern.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

Package rerunfilecheck Info: Checksums for `modern.out':
(rerunfilecheck)             Before: <no file>
(rerunfilecheck)             After:  322BEBFCABCA5EDBE025FC176AD1AC25;300.
 )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 29836 strings out of 478277
 632444 string characters out of 5839274
 1874482 words of memory out of 5000000
 49412 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 516400 words of font info for 77 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 319 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 129i,13n,122p,1030b,485s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

Output written on output/2023/7/96/38/1/modern.pdf (2 pages).
```

Comment: latex will not drop characters with no warning, what does the log say?

Comment: There is really not much information you're giving us to work with … We have no idea about your setup, what distribution you are using or even the error message you're getting, let alone an MWE that shows your code.

Comment: I have add more detail info about this issue. @Ingmar

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with your example and an up-to-date TeX Live 2023. See [here](https://i.imgur.com/JtKrgEP.png) what I get. Please have a look into the `log` file, if there are some error messages or warnings about missing packages or fonts.

Comment: I am not use the texlive 2023, the texlive 2023 works fine.  I am using the latex 2023 small with extra package(the texlive contains full package up to 4GB, my texlive only 100MB+): ctex moderncv fontawesome5 fontawesome academicons multirow arydshln

Answer (score 3):

If you add `\showoutput` in a working version you see

```
...........\TU/fontawesomefree/solid/n/9 glyph#562
...........\penalty 10000
...........\glue 2.997 plus 1.49849 minus 0.999
...........\special{pdf:bann<</Type/Annot/Subtype/Link/Border[0 0 0]/H/I/C[0 1 
1]/A<</S/U\ETC.}
...........\TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/it/9 15576865433


...........\TU/fontawesomefree/regular/n/9 glyph#97
...........\penalty 10000
...........\glue 2.997 plus 1.49849 minus 0.999
...........\special{pdf:bann<</Type/Annot/Subtype/Link/Border[0 0 0]/H/I/C[0 1 
1]/A<</S/U\ETC.}
...........\TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/it/9 demo@gmail.com


...........\TU/fontawesomebrands/regular/n/9 glyph#112
...........\penalty 10000
...........\glue 2.997 plus 1.49849 minus 0.999
...........\special{pdf:bann<</Type/Annot/Subtype/Link/Border[0 0 0]/H/I/C[0 1 
1]/A<</S/U\ETC.}
...........\TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/it/9 https://stackoverflow.com/users/
2628868/dolphin


...........\TU/fontawesomebrands/regular/n/9 glyph#97
...........\penalty 10000
...........\glue 2.997 plus 1.49849 minus 0.999
...........\special{pdf:bann<</Type/Annot/Subtype/Link/Border[0 0 0]/H/I/C[0 1 
1]/A<</S/U\ETC.}
...........\TU/lmroman10-regular.otf(0)/m/it/9 https://github.com/reddwarf
```

so compared to your image, the icons that work are in `\TU/fontawesomebrands/regular/n/9` and those that do not work are in `\TU/fontawesomefree/solid/n/9` and `\TU/fontawesomefree/regular/n/9`

so adding

```
\expandafter\show\csname TU/fontawesomefree/regular/n/9\endcsname
\expandafter\show\csname TU/fontawesomefree/solid/n/9\endcsname
```

shows

```
\TU/fontawesomefree/regular/n/9=select font "[FontAwesome5Free-Regular-400.ot
f]:script=latn;" at 9.0pt.
> \TU/fontawesomefree/solid/n/9=select font "[FontAwesome5Free-Solid-900.otf]:s
cript=latn;" at 9.0pt.
```

So your minimal installation is missing `FontAwesome5Free-Regular-400.otf` and `FontAwesome5Free-Solid-900.otf`

Comment: Does OP's "this is the log output" not count as showing the log?  It has several "Font shape ... undefined using ... instead" messages.  But it doesn't appear to mention the two otf files you mention.

Comment: @Teepeemm oops thanks, I'll adjust

Comment: @Teepeemm well the relevant part of the log is not shown (around line 196) `LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TU+fontawesomefree on i
nput line 69.`  which is before the part shown.